# The boundary of a compact set of positive measure has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a surface $M$ and a compact subset $K \subset M$ with positive Lebesgue measure. I have a certain function $\ f : K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, which I want to integrate over $K$. The problem is, that I don't know yet if $f$ is a measurable function. What I can show is, that the restriction of $f$ onto the interior is measurable. Now, if I could argue that the boundary of $K$ is a measure-zero set, my problem should be solved because I can then integrate over $K$ without the boundary.

Is there something like: "The boundary of a compact set of positive measure has measure zero"?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Isn't it immeadiate? I mean, take all connex components of $\partial K=K\setminus K^{\circ}$, then you know that each one is homeomorphic to a segment, that is, there exists $h$ homeomorphism that sends each component to the set $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which has measure 0. Another thing is why $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has Lebesgue measure 0, but this you can show by covering it with "inflated" 2-dimensional rectangles, compute its measure and then let them become smaller and smaller and you will obtain 0.

Comment: This isn't true. There are "fat" cantor (compact) sets which have nonzero positive measure boundaries. I'll let someone better at it explain Cantor sets, but see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set.